# How can I use instanceof inside a custom type guard in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typeguards, narrowing

I'm trying to create a custom type guard using an `instanceof` but strangely it isn't working as expected in the else clause

This is an example with the related playground link:
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gXwLACgDRIYBBNASwFswQs9D9h0IAXaCiBZdaAXmgAKFACMAVgC44SVBgA+0ctVoBKKaLEcY3WfwB80DRzRswaYPBQAzaTzQBuIi3aclNOgOHipO3greq6uJaipTu+obBFCasZhbWocogjozMMdCs8Gw+Mn6J4QJo8ADutrKCKikEFFaCmWzGpuaWNgEgKpgE0BlZrPbQAPQD0GkN9axSbQQM8CAQ8FhdPWz9QyPOyxNl6NME1bWuYbR1vSodS+Orw6Ps45NHILv4s-OL+N2Xg9cbd9BFAG5IaZAA)

```js
class Person {}

class Animal {}

const isPerson = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Person => obj instanceof Person;
const isAnimal = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Animal => obj instanceof Animal;

const test: Person | Animal = new Person();

if(test instanceof Animal){
  test; // const test: Animal
}
else {
  test; // const test: Person
}

if(isAnimal(test)){
  test; // const test: Animal
}
else {
  test; // const test: never

}
```

I would expect to have test to be of type `Person` in the else clause, but it is of type `never`... why?

I know that I can also use directly the instanceof, but I would prefer to have a more concise function like those created

UPDATE:
With this little edit the type guard is working right... why?!
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDWgAdEBLANzABd5oAPe6AXmgCJ7aW8BfPPUSGAEE0JALZgQWPAWLkqNdk1btOuHrj7oIlaCQgJk6JQAoUAIwBWALjhJUGAD7RhYiQEob5i7pgH7TAD5oL100bTA0YHgUADNbQzQAbk0wnT0XcUlmU0sbPyMnDPdPSx9nEUzA4NKSVIio2PLXEGSNXAATeH5EGmAtHWptPLsCpszWvBIY40G0usjouKKQNxx8aFnE6AB6beg+1I34IbGJbjx4EAgaNYJNnb2D7SOT-LRztqnjdIqJGePKG5VtIXpQtrt9v1QTZlh9LtcpOt7hCngMAcMEtwgA)

```js
class Person {
  private xxx = "xxx"
}

class Animal {
  private xxx = "xxx"
}

const isPerson = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Person => obj instanceof Person;
const isAnimal = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Animal => obj instanceof Animal;

declare const test: Person | Animal;

if(test instanceof Animal){
  test; // const test: Animal
}
else {
  test; // const test: Person
}

if(isAnimal(test)){
  test; // const test: Animal
}
else {
  test; // const test: Person
}
```

Comment: It is because the union type you define is not discriminated.

Comment: Using `test instanceof Animal` in place of `isAnimal(test)` works though

Comment: I added an example using instanceof

Comment: According to me a type predicate enforces the final type (like a cast would do) but it's not taken into account in the control flow narrowing. I guess you have no other choice than use bare `instanceof`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript performs [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). And it sees that `Person` and `Animal` actually have the *same* structure.

So if `test is Animal` is `false`, it infers that `test is Person` is `false` as well. Hence the resulting `never` type left.

By having unique properties in `Person` and `Animal`, now their structure is different, and TypeScript correctly gives you the `Person` type left in the `else` block.

```
class Person {
  common = 0
  //person = 0
}

class Animal {
  common = 0
  animal = 0
}

const isPerson = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Person => obj instanceof Person;
const isAnimal = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Animal => obj instanceof Animal;

declare const test: Person | Animal;

if (test instanceof Animal) {
  test; // const test: Animal
}
else {
  test; // const test: Person
}

if (isAnimal(test)) {
  test; // const test: Animal
}
else {
  test; // const test: Person
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDWmBQFtj1oBeaABjwIHp6AHJVDK23AXzz1EhgBBNAEtiYEFjqESZdjWlhR4yRzw9cfdBAAu0ERATJyVABQoARgCsAXHFbkAPtGFiJASjuWr+mEbaUAHzQ3vpoukrA8CgAZvbGaADcWuF6Bq4qlNDm1nb+Ti7KHl7WvoVuqsGhIqmR0XEZEsmauAAm8PyI8DKp0DrwunkOGM6NILy4InGm-bphEWhRseUq7lL4fQM6idCMPXOzOnZj0owAegD86njwIBDdOBuHO3tEvYdDCaf0l9ctU9l0kUQDMtu41o8CM9dvR9noPisJN9ftwbncHtJoa9tPCtp82MirqjcEA)

---

Note: beware of `const test: UnionType = oneOfTheTypes;`, TypeScript performs [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments), so it it is still able to infer that `test` is actually one of the types only.

---

On the other hand, [narrowing with `instanceof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) works differently:

> in JavaScript `x instanceof Foo` checks whether the prototype chain of `x` contains `Foo.prototype`.

TypeScript obviously replicates this behaviour, hence it does not apply structural typing, but prototype inheritance check.

---

After question edit:

By adding a unique field (or a private field) to `Animal`, we explicitly break the possibility that `Person` somehow extends `Animal`. It is a similar situation to my above code sample.

So now TypeScript treats them as 2 totally unrelated types, and the control flow behaves as you expect (i.e. `test` is a `Person` in the `else` block).

---

On the contrary, should `Person` *extend* `Animal`, we now *explicitly* relate the 2 types, and TypeScript now knows that if `test` is not an `Animal`, it is not a `Person` either (hence `test` is back to `never` in the `else` block), including when using `instanceof`! (Since in that case we create a class inheritance)

```
class Animal {
  private xxx = "xxx"
}

class Person extends Animal {
  private xxx2 = "xxx"
}

const isPerson = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Person => obj instanceof Person;
const isAnimal = (obj: Person | Animal): obj is Animal => obj instanceof Animal;

declare const test: Person | Animal;

if (test instanceof Animal) {
  test; // const test: Animal | Person
}
else {
  test; // const test: never
}

if (isAnimal(test)) {
  test; // const test: Animal | Person
}
else {
  test; // const test: never
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeBYAUNaADgE6IBuYALgKbQAe90AvNAET20u4C+uuokMAApUiEAPbxoVWtXgATGAhRpMufMTKUa7AExNW7Tjh44+EiBWiIIw0RP0AKMQCMAVgC5ot8ZIA+cJFQQAEpPF1crIREfJgA+aHCreAsweGAqMQAzL2iJAG4zZMtrJSDHcM9ve39StFCEt0iA5XRGeMTEItT0rOaggtMcOSp+Ihpgc0tqC0rcvz60AdxEbIdp4q60jOzakNU8aHW86AB6E+gJosOqGYX0fyr4NVOTgD0Afm5cKhAIGmwDkcXhdJtdbvAqKQRM8zh8voMVtAHCVAmg1jcKMFgvt8ECziCrutPLtoA85jC3p9jN9fv9nnjzpcLGCKJ4IVCiBS4dScEA)

Comment: so in this case the only way is using instanceof directly?

Comment: please, check the edit on the answer

Comment: "_so in this case the only way is using instanceof directly?_": if by "this case", you mean when `Person` and `Animal` have the same structure, then indeed, a custom type predicate with `obj is type` will not be able to differentiate them, whereas `instanceof` will.

Comment: Wow, yours is a great answer! So in this case a simply workaround could be to add a private field even if not used